# запаковка и распаковка 7z с параметрами

Tags: windows, консоль, 7z

```
//нажимаю правой кнопкой на папку ( d:/doc )
//добавить к архиву
//выбираю путь ( c:/arc/myarc.zip )
//выбираю уровень сжатия ( без сжатия )
//ввожу пароль
//выбираю метод шифрования AES-256
//ОК
```

Может ли кто команду подсказать консольную ( ест-но для Windows XP-10 ), что бы можно было описанный выше действия осуществить?

Comment: На сайте 7z в разделе FAQ всё есть, зайдите и почитайте ключи и как с консоли в батнике запускать там всё в примерах!

Comment: простые примеры там есть, а вот указать метод сжатия, пароль и прочее - нету. или я не увидел

Comment: Да, действительно, но всё вроде есть в справке, посмотрите в самой программе справку (F1)

Comment: Обратите внимание на Command Line Version -> Switches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подробнее по ключам смотрите в Справке 7z (F1), Command Line Version -> Switches

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -sfx "D:\doc1.exe" -psecret -mhe "D:\doc" -mx0`

где ключи:

```
-sfx  самораспаковывающийся архив;
-p задает пароль (secret);
-mhe шифрование;
-mx0 метод сжатия
```